# Access all UILabel objects in a tableView cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiwebview, uilabel, tableview

I have a ton of labels & web views in a cell which I want to hide when user is in portrait mode. I tried the following:

```
for subview in cell.subviews {

                print("i am a subview")
                if let label = subview as? UILabel {

                    label.hidden = true
                }
            }
```

I get three subviews but those are no UILabels. In general I have >10 Labels which is why this code does not seem to work. Any hints on how to access those Labels in a loop? Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing subviews of UITableViewCell but you need to get subviews of contentView of UITableViewCell.

`For Example:
cell.subviews[0].subviews` will do.

Comment: Finally! Thanks... Made my day.

Comment: why wouldn't you use the explicit reference, you can't actually guarantee that it's the first subview...

Comment: first subview will always be contentview of UITableViewCell

Comment: What are the two other ones?

Answer (score 0):

For myself, I solved pretty same problem by declaring `labelsArray: [UILabel]` property in cell and adding pointers to label when creating to this array.

Other way - using tags. Since setting same tag to different views is bad style coding, you can provide some formulas: for example assume your labels will have tags 1000, 1001, 1002 ... . Then you can enumerate all labels by cycle, getting view with tag from 1000 until you will receive `nil`

Comment: you could also use an outlet collection for that

Comment: @Wain if you use xib/storyboards, yes.